# display tables horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I want to display 3 tables horizontally aligned.
i have used css to display tables horizontally using **display: inline-block;** . but could not show tables horizontally. Please suggest how can i show multiple tables horizontally in a page.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding "float: left" to the css?

Comment: float:left is allowing to display 4 tables horizontally, i want to display 3 tables horizontally - @Obscure Geek.

Comment: Try setting the width of the column such that only 3 tables fit horizontally else add margin between the tables.